# Ногти и "рукти"

Tags: этимология

В книге К. Чуковского "От двух до пяти" есть такая фраза: "Почему ты говоришь: ногти! Ногти у нас на ногах. А которые на руках — это рукти". А действительно, почему?)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна из версий
Русские слова НОГОТЬ, НОГТИ (К-(н)ОГОТЬ, К(-)ОГОТЬ, КОГТИ) произошли от еврейского слова НаГаТи '(я) трогал'. Еврейское окончание -ТИ означает то же, что ныне по-русски означает окончание -Л глаголов (пр. вр. III л. ед. ч). (с)

Comment: Согласно  Фасмеру  слово  НОГОТЬ - общеславянское  и  производится  от  слова   НОГА.  Ребёнок-то  оказывается  прав !

Answer (score 1):

Согласно  Фасмеру,  Преображенскому,  Черных  слово  "ноготь"  восходит  к  слову  "нога"  в  его  древнем   значении  "копыто".   Ногти  это  маленькие  копытца   на   кончиках  пальцев  вообще,  независимо  на  каких  конечностях   эти  пальцы  растут.  Только  нужно  читать  обе  словарных  статьи:  и  про  ногу,  и  про  ногти.

Answer (score 0):

http://russkieslogi.ru/kogot-nogot.html

Слова: коготь, ноготь

Очень интересный случай. Пара русских слов, которую сформировали авторы словаря. Читаем.

Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка.  КОГОТЬ. Искон. Суф. производное (суф. -ът- > -от-) от той же основы, что диал. кокша «крюк», кокши «сустав птичьего крыла», др.-в.-нем. hakô «крюк» и т. д. Кокоть (ср. диал. кокоток «сустав») > коготь, вероятно, под влиянием ноготь.

НОГОТЬ. Общеслав. Суф. уменьшит.-ласкат. производное от нога. Конец цитаты.

Форму слова «коготь» словарь объяснить не может. Так и сяк сопоставляет со словами «кокша», «кокши», «кокоть», «hakô». Убедительно перейти к словоформе «коготь» не получается. И тогда делается пассаж:  «коготь, вероятно, под влиянием ноготь». Почему коготь стал походить на ноготь, не объясняется. Нельзя же предположение «вероятно, под влиянием» считать научным доказательством возникновения словоформы. С таким же успехом можно предположить, что слово «коготь» возникло потому, что хорошо рифмуется со словом «ноготь».

Читаем далее. Этимология слова «ноготь» ещё забавнее. Да и не этимология это вовсе. Это поэзия. Уменьшительно-ласкательное от слова «нога»! Малюсенькая ноженька. Блеск. Ноготь, это малюсенькая ноженька! То ли это громадный ноготь величиной с детскую ногу, то ли это тараканья ножка величиной с ноготок? Если бы такое заявил нормальный человек, то ему бы сказали, что у него белая горячка. Давайте разбираться.

1. коготь

Буквально: по окружности (ко) поднимается изнутри (го) прочно присоединённый к основанию (ть)

Подымающийся изнутри, по окружности и соединённый с основой. Коготь выпускается из специальной сумки на пальцах лапы хищника. Т.е. поднимается изнутри. Выпускается коготь по кривой траектории, по окружности, как сабля из ножен. По другому не получится, т.к. коготь имеет загнутую, кривую форму.  Одной стороной коготь прочно присоединён к основанию, к последней фаланге пальца животного.

1. ноготь

Буквально: не (но) поднимается изнутри (го) прочно присоединённый к основанию (ть)

Не поднимающееся и соединённое с основой — явная антитеза слову «коготь».

Как сейчас говорят: «вы поняли, в чём прикол?». Поясню. Этимологический словарь перепутал причину и следствие. Словарь считает, что словоформа «коготь» вторична по отношению к слову «ноготь». На самом деле всё с точностью до наоборот. Слово коготь имеет прозрачный исходный смысл. Оно точно описывает особенность оружия хищной лапы. Слово «ноготь» противопоставляется слову «коготь». Ноготь не поднимается, не выпускается из пальца человека. Тоже точное описание, но подразумевается знакомство с когтем.

Comment: В  чём  прикол  понял.  Но  вы  не  исходите  из  предположения,  что  древнейшее  значение  слова  нога  -  это  копыто.  А  если  это  принять  к  сведению,  то  ногти  -  это  маленькие  копытца ( похожие  на  копытца ),  что  проще  и  с  грамматической  и  с  анатомической  позиции.  Особенно  для  ногтей  на  ногах - ими  даже  не  царапаются.  Выводить  "ноготь"  из  "коготь"  гораздо  более  сложная  и  надуманная  конструкция.  Кроме  того  когти  выпускаются  не  у  всех  зверей  и  птиц.  У  кошек  -  да,  у  собак -  нет.  К  тому  же  они  не  поднимаются,  а  выпускаются  вниз.